# Count spaces in NumberFormat with ExcelScript using OfficeScripts in Excel for Web

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have to count the spaces within in NumberFormat of each cell in column A. Here is an example NumberFormat:

```
"                       "@
```

I translated my VBA code into OfficeScripts ExcelScript (for Excel for Web) but it seems that the replace function doesn't removes the spaces:

```
sheet.getRange("A1").getNumberFormat().length - sheet.getRange("A1").getNumberFormat().replace(" ", "").length
```

Is there another option to count the spaces or did I something wrong with the replace function (other letters will be replaced correctly)

Answer (score 2):

It's just the JavaScript syntax and the solution is:

```
sheet.getRange("A1").getNumberFormat().length - sheet.getRange("A1").getNumberFormat().replace(\s/g, "").length
```